# Backing up my Bluray collection

Tags: media, blu-ray

This may not be the place to ask this question but I thought I would give it a shot. Is there a device that I can take the HDMI output from my bluray player to a device that will record full 1080p and audio in a format that I can turn into a MKV for backup purposes?

I am aware of the software that could aid me in this but so far everything I have tried fails. I just want a simple way to take what I own and make a digital backup.

Thanks for any light that can be spread on this topic.

Comment: If you have tried existing solutions that didn't work for you, please name them and explain why they didn't work for you.

Comment: You may want to just get a Blu-ray drive for your computer...

Comment: As far as I know devices with an HDMI in rarely if ever allow you to record the signal.  You will need to look into software to rip the content.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a device.  It would be called a "capture card".

For example, the [Blackmagic Design Intensity](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/intensity/).  It has HDMI inputs, will capture HD, and will process uncompressed HD as well.  You also didn't say anything about your actual computer (desktop, laptop... available slots in a desktop, etc) which would **NORMALLY** present even more of a problem suggesting a solution for you, since how can we know what kind of computer accessory to suggest, if we don't know what kind of computer it is for... right?  But in this case, the Blackmagic also has three different versions.  Two are portable and will connect to either desktops or laptops... one is a PCI-E x1 card.

Now.  Is this the **ONLY** device out there?  Nope.  Just one.  All I did was use a search engine to look for *HDMI capture card*.  Yep.

Here's another one.  [The AverTv](http://www.avermedia-usa.com/AVerTV/product/ProductDetail.aspx?Id=482&tab=APDriver).  It also has HDMI inputs for HD capture.

Starting to see how this works?  There are lots of HDMI capture devices out there, and they are actually kind of easy to find.

Now, if you were asking about some stand alone device... then I'd expect this question to be closed soon, as you aren't asking about computer hardware.  Actually, it will probably be closed any way due to the facts that it is really just a shopping question, and one where you didn't do much research on your own first.

Regarding Software... once you have captured it, you aren't needing to convert a rip.  That's very different.  Once it has been captured (like making a 1-to-1 dub copy), then it is just a matter of converting it.

But Oliver is right.  You need to detail how you have failed previously and with what software you failed.  What you want to do is not something simple that you can plug and one step.

**EDIT**  The more I think about it, the more Bob is right.  Just get a Blue-Ray optical drive for your computer.